# jQuery/PHP dynamic form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sql

I'm looking for a way to submit multiple dynamic form fields in a single submission.
Each row of data when submitted will share certain attributes:
*job id, client, type of work.*
While also keeping their own independent variables:
*role, name, tvl, start date, end date, start time, end time.*

I think my solution will either require a for loop or the use of multi dimensional arrays (maybe both?) but I can't quite figure out where in my code to implement that or how to do so.

At the moment - only 1 "employee" is showing up in my database - typically the last entry made in the "details" div.

Here is the code:

**HTML**
index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="include/ajax.inc.php" class="ajax">
                  <h2>Job Details</h2>
                  <br>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Job ID</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a" id="a">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Client</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select type="text" class="form-control" name="b" id="b">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                        <option value="OPTION1" name="OPTION1">OPTION1</option>
                        <option value="OPTION2" name="OPTION2">OPTION2</option>
                        
                     
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Type of Work</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <select type="text" class="form-control" name="c" id="c">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                        <option value="OPTION1" name="OPTION1">OPTION1</option>
                        <option value="OPTION2" name="OPTION2">OPTION2</option>
                      
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                  <h2>Employee Details</h2>
                  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-rounded m-sm" id="add">
                    <small>ADD EMPLOYEE</small>
                  </button>
                  <!--- ADD EMPLOYEES --->
                  <div class="ibox" id="details" name="details[]">
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">Position</label>
                            <select class="form-control" type="text" name="d" id="d">
                              <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
                              <option value="ROLE1" name="SPV">ROLE1</option>
                              <option value="ROLE2" name="REG">ROLE2</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="e" id="e">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">TVL</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f" id="f">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="g" id="g">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">End Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="h" id="h">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">Start Time</label>
                            <input type="time" class="form-control" name="i" id="i">
                          </div>

                          <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">End Time</label>
                            <input type="time" class="form-control" name="j" id="j">
                          </div>
                          <div class="col text-right m-t-lg">
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--- ADD EMPLOYEES END --->
                  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-med" name="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
<!-- SCCRIPT-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**JS**
main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var html = ' <div class="ibox" id="details" name="details[i]"> <div class="ibox-content"> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Position</label> <select class="form-control" type="text" name="d" id="d"> <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option> <option value="SPV" name="SPV">SPV</option> <option value="REG" name="REG">REG</option> </select> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="e" id="e"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">TVL</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f" id="f"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Start Date</label> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="g" id="g"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">End Date</label> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="h" id="h"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Start Time</label> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="i" id="i"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">End Time</label> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="j" id="j"> </div> <div class="col text-right m-t-lg"> </div> <div class="col text-right m-t-lg"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-danger" id="remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </button> </div></div> </div> </div> </div>'

  // Add rows to the form
    $(function() {
    $('#add').click(function(e) {
      $('#details').append(html);
      e.preventDefault();
      });

   // Remove rows from the form 
    $(this).on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('#details').remove();
    });

  });


});


$('form.ajax').on('submit', function() {

  var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[id]').each(function(index, value){
      var that = $(this),
      name = that.attr('id'),
      value = that.val();
      data[name] = value;

    });

  $.ajax ({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    }


  });

  return false;

});
```

**PHP**
ajax.inc.php

```
<?php
    include 'form.dbh.php'; {

    
    $jobid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['a']);
    $client = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['b']);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['c']);
    $role = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['d']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['e']);
    $tvl = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['f']);
    $sdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['g']);
    $edate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['h']);
    $stime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['i']);
    $etime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['j']);



    $sql = "INSERT INTO timesheets(jobid, client, type, role, name, tvl, sdate, edate, stime, etime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
      echo "SQL error";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssssss', $jobid, $client, $type, $role, $name, $tvl, $sdate, $edate, $stime, $etime);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

  }

  header("Location:../index.php?success");
  }

 ?>
```

Does anyone have an idea? or any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With Form Submissions, you will want to prevent the default action when you are performing AJAX calls. It would best to add an event variable, `e` and then call `.preventDefault()` in the callback.

Comment: Also I see that you have `that` being used twice in the same callback. It should be separated, yet it might be ambiguous enough that it overwrites the original `that`. As a rule of thumb, use unique variable names when possible.

Comment: Please provide more insights - which part of your application is not working as expected? It's very unlikely that your problem covers Javascript, PHP, HTML, jQuery **and** SQL, all in once

Comment: I'm looking to submit multiple appended entries in a single submit function- at the moment only one entry(the last child) is being submitted while the other appended entries, including the parent entry are not being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```
$(function() {

  var html = ' <div class="ibox" id="details" name="details[i]"> <div class="ibox-content"> <div class="container"> <div class="row"> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Position</label> <select class="form-control" type="text" name="d" id="d"> <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option> <option value="SPV" name="SPV">SPV</option> <option value="REG" name="REG">REG</option> </select> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="e" id="e"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">TVL</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f" id="f"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Start Date</label> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="g" id="g"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">End Date</label> <input type="date" class="form-control" name="h" id="h"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">Start Time</label> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="i" id="i"> </div> <div class="col"> <label class="form-label">End Time</label> <input type="time" class="form-control" name="j" id="j"> </div> <div class="col text-right m-t-lg"> </div> <div class="col text-right m-t-lg"> <button class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-danger" id="remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </button> </div></div> </div> </div> </div>'


  $('#add').click(function(e) {
    $('#details').append(html);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Remove rows from the form 
  $(this).on('click', '#remove', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('#details').remove();
  });

  $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var that = $(this),
      u = that.attr('action'),
      t = that.attr('method'),
      d = {};

    that.find('[id]').each(function(i, el) {
      d[$(el).attr("id")] = $(el).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: u,
      type: t,
      data: d,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

This cleans up some of the issues you are seeing. When using `.each()` you will have an Index and Element, not a Value.

**Update**

The code above will submit all data based on the `form.ajax` selector. When you have only one section of details in the form, that is all the data that will be submitted. If you add your HTML, you cause an HTML/JS issue where the ID attributes of the elements are no longer Unique. All IDs must be unique.

Consider ignoring the IDs and make use of `name` attribute instead. When you gather the data, for `d` through `j`, these would need to be Arrays, since these are the items that repeat.

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function getData(f) {
    var myData = {
      a: $("[name='a']", f).val(),
      b: $("[name='b']", f).val(),
      c: $("[name='c']", f).val(),
      d: [],
      e: [],
      f: [],
      g: [],
      h: [],
      i: [],
      j: []
    };
    var k, v;
    $("[name]", f).each(function(i, el) {
      k = $(el).attr("name");
      v = $(el).val();
      if (i > 2) {
        myData[k].push(v);
      }
    });
    console.log(myData);
    return myData;
  }

  $('#add').click(function(e) {
    var html = $("#details > .ibox-content:eq(0)").clone(true);
    $(".col:last", html).html("<button class='btn btn-sm btn-rounded btn-danger remove' id='remove-" + $(".ibox-content").length + "'> <i class='fa fa-times'></i> </button>");
    $(".ibox-content:last").after(html);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#details").on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.ibox-content').remove();
  });

  $("form.ajax").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      type: "POST",
      data: getData(this),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="include/ajax.inc.php" class="ajax">
  <h2>Job Details</h2>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Job ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a" id="a">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Client</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select type="text" class="form-control" name="b" id="b">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="OPTION1">OPTION1</option>
        <option value="OPTION2">OPTION2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Type of Work</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select type="text" class="form-control" name="c" id="c">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="OPTION1">OPTION1</option>
        <option value="OPTION2">OPTION2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

  <h2>Employee Details</h2>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-rounded m-sm" id="add"><small>ADD EMPLOYEE</small></button>
  <!--- ADD EMPLOYEES --->
  <div id="details" class="ibox">
    <div class="ibox-content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">Position</label>
            <select class="form-control" type="text" name="d" id="d">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
              <option value="ROLE1">ROLE1</option>
              <option value="ROLE2">ROLE2</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="e" id="e">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">TVL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f" id="f">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">Start Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="g" id="g">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">End Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="h" id="h">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">Start Time</label>
            <input type="time" class="form-control" name="i" id="i">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label class="form-label">End Time</label>
            <input type="time" class="form-control" name="j" id="j">
          </div>
          <div class="col text-right m-t-lg">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--- ADD EMPLOYEES END --->
  <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-med">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You may notice, only specific elements have the `name` attribute now. DIV elements should not use `name` and the same goes for OPTION. DIV is not a part of a Form. OPTION is a element part of SELECT which is the parent container and the form element, this should have `name`.

Your PHP will get a complex payload of data. For example:

```
{
  "a": "2020",
  "b": "OPTION1",
  "c": "OPTION2",
  "d": [
    "ROLE1",
    "ROLE2"
  ],
  "e": [
    "Bob",
    "Nancy"
  ],
  "f": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  "g": [
    "2020-10-12",
    "2020-10-12"
  ],
  "h": [
    "2020-10-16",
    "2020-10-16"
  ],
  "i": [
    "08:00",
    "08:00"
  ],
  "j": [
    "12:00",
    "12:00"
  ]
}
```

You will need to adjust your PHP to handle this new data format.

Comment: Thank you! This cleans it up nicely but I still have the issue of only 1 entry being submitted into the database. I would like to submit more than one entry upon the submit click, should this be done with a forloop?

Comment: Edit: To clarify - this edit has allowed me to "submit" the next entry, which is a huge improvement but I believe what I'm trying to do is "submit" all entries - at once rather than in succession of each other

Comment: @jadew I am glad it did. If it answers your question, I hope you will Mark it as the Answer as well as Upvote.

Comment: will do! One last question - as I add a new element/variable in `var myData` I'm facing an error. For instance, I want to add another variable above `a: $("[name='a']", f).val(),` named `id: $("[name='id']", f).val(),` (following the same rules as variables a,b,c) When I do this  `myData[k].push(v);` and `var k,v;` become unidentifiable. Can you suggest why that is and what the solution may be?